# Retrieving information from a database through php

Tags: php

I have been coding a webform for facilities that when you select a facility it should bring up the relevant carpark i.e the one closest to it. I know my `$result` is wrong just dont know how to fix it:

```
$servername = 'servername';

$username = 'username';

$password = 'password';

$SQL = mysql_connect($servername, $username, $password);


$queryNumber = $_GET['query'];

switch ($queryNumber) {  
  case "q1":

    echo "<p>Query 1</p>";

$_GET['facility'];

    echo "<p id='sql'>".$SQL."</p>";  
    echo "<table>";
    echo "   <th>Carpark</th>";
    $result = "SELECT nearbyfacilities, campus FROM CarPark"; // names of columns in my database
    while ( $db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        echo "<tr><td>" . $db_field['carpark'] . "</tr></td>";
      }
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need use `mysql_query()` to send your query to the db before fetching the results with `mysql_fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Also, consider using mysqli (or pdo) instead of mysql, as php's mysql functions have been deprecated in favor of mysqli.

Answer (score 1):

You don't query anywhere the DB. You need to execute `mysqli_query()` with the db handler and the query string. That line is missing from your code. It should be like this:

```
$query = "SELECT nearbyfacilities, campus FROM CarPark"; // names of columns in my database
$result = mysqli_query($SQL, $query);
while ( $db_field = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) { ... }
```

Also change all `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*`

Comment: Makes sense now. I've gotten the script to run, however when it does run no information is returned. I think its down to the $query code im running. Any ideas?